# Could not resolve us.us.archive.ubuntu.com for ubuntu 20.04 on WSL

Tags: 20.04, updates, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running an ubuntu (`focal 20.04`) on `WSL2` and i am trying to install gcc and it seems i need to run `apt-get update` first.
I keep getting `Could not resolve us.us.archive.ubuntu.com` (error below).
I have checked for solutions and edited the `/etc/resolv.conf` adding the additional nameservers like below:

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the foll>
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.17.96.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

**Error**

```
sanzor@DESKTOP-GOMS8S8:~/rust$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for sanzor: 
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed InRelease [267 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                              
Ign:3 http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com/debian focal InRelease                                      
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease                         
Hit:5 http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com/debian focal Release                                        
Err:6 http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                           
  Could not resolve 'us.us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:7 http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                   
  Could not resolve 'us.us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease                       
Err:10 http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease       
  Could not resolve 'us.us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security InRelease             
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates InRelease              
Hit:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-proposed InRelease            
Hit:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports InRelease           
Hit:15 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease
Hit:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release
Fetched 381 kB in 1s (379 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**P.S**
I do not know why it goes for `us.us.archive.ubuntu.com` , or in which file to look for that setting to change , if i can.

**Later Edit**

This is the */etc/apt/sources.list* file content:

```
sanzor@DESKTOP-GOMS8S8:/etc/apt$ cat sources.list
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-proposed main
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Why does it say us.us? Seems your sources is wrong.

Comment: Tried to use a browser to get there just to double check. This site can’t be reached Check if there is a typo in us.us.archive.ubuntu.com.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: Do you know which file i should check for ? I don't know why it goes for those sites.

Comment: The source list /etc/apt/sources. list and the files contained in /etc/apt/sources. list. d/ are designed to support any number of active sources and a variety of source media.

Comment: There should not be us.us it should only be one us

Comment: @David where should i look for in which file and edit ? I added the content of `sources.list` file in the original post.

Comment: Get rid of the PPA entry it is not even for this release of Ubuntu and edit all the us.us to only have one us

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by editing the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.
All urls were `us.us.archive.ubuntu.com/...` and i changed to `us.archive.com`

All worked like a charm afterwards.